# Jack points for a 2001 BMW X5

Tags: bmw, x5

I know of 4 jack points (2 just behind the front wheels and 2 just in front of the rear wheels) that fit the scissor jack which comes with the vehicle. I want to raise the back of the car and put jack stands under the 2 rear jack points. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the scissor-jack on a structural part of the under-carriage near the jack-point, place jack stands under the mentioned jack-point and lower the scissor-jack this way to jack the car side by side. You could also use the rear-differential to lift the whole back (at once) and place both jack-stands under the 2 rear jack-points at once. Don't use the side of the subframe or the control arm support on this vehicle.

May be unnecessarily: Use handbrake, use wheel-blocks and maybe use wood or a rubber-pad on jacks to protect your car.

Comment: Finding a proper "structural part of the under-carriage near the jack-point" is harder than I expected! Thanks for the reminder about handbrake and chocking the wheels.